# bad request when trying to print a page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print a page using javascript, and i am getting a "Bad Request" when a new window popsup if i clicked the 'print' button.
 Here is my javascript code that opens a window by capturing the current location and assigning the media css to print.

```
function printerFriendlyNew() {
    genPopUp = window.open("","printer","toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,directories=no,status=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,width=760,height=600");
    genPopUp.location.href = document.location.href + "&css=print";
    if (genPopUp.opener == null) genPopUp.opener = window;
    genPopUp.opener.name = "opener";
}
```

Any idea why i get the 'bad request' error ?

Comment: got this resolved...crazy me, am just blindly appending "&css=print" since i have url's which have querystring, and it works fine for those, and bugs out for those which does'nt.  
I added this to my existing javascript and this resolved the issue.

 var contain = document.location.href;

    if (contain.indexOf('?') == -1)
        genPopUp.location.href = contain + "?css=print";
    else
        genPopUp.location.href = contain + "&css=print";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this resolved... crazy me, am just blindly appending "&css=print" since I have URLs which have querystring, and it works fine for those, and bugs out for those which don't. I added this to my existing javascript and this resolved the issue.

```
var contain = document.location.href; 
if (contain.indexOf('?') == -1) 
  genPopUp.location.href = contain + "?css=print"; 
else 
  genPopUp.location.href = contain + "&css=print";
```